# How to get a javascript variable value?

Tags: javascript

```
var param = "statut";

// I want this expression :

data.param.function1().function2();

// to be equivalent to :

data.statut.function1().function2();
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors. `data[param]function1().function2()`

Square bracket notation allows you to dynamically access properties of an Object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
var param = 'status';
data[param]function1().function2()
```